# Overriding method with similar body

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

I have two classes: One and Two

```
class One:
    # self.a, self.b, self.c
    # ...
    def foo(self):
        self.a.foo()
        self.b.bar()
        self.c.hmm(1,2,3)

class Two(One):
    # super(Two, self).__init__()
    # self.d
    # ...
    def foo(self):
        self.a.foo()
        self.b.bar()
        self.d.wow()
        self.c.hmm(4,5,6)
```

One and Two's `foo()` methods are similar enough that I feel like I'm copy-pasting code.
I know I could have a separate `foo2()` method in One that executes the shared code and add arguments to `foo()` for the different values, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Are a, b and c instance of some other class?

Comment: Yes, they are. a, b, c are the same type of class in both One and Two.

Answer (score 4):

To extend a method from a super class, you can use `super`.

```
class One:
    ...

    def foo(self):
        self.a.foo()
        self.b.bar()
        self.c.hmm(1,2,3)

class Two(One):
    ...

    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        self.d.wow()
```

Notice this will not preserve the order in which the methods are called. So if that order matters you do have to rewrite the whole `foo` method.